# Where Multiple Values SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, where-clause

For this code I need the sum of the serv1 - serv8 where the student is receiving "Speech Language Therapy". I can not for the life of me figure out how to get those. If I say where serv1 equals 'SLT' then it will show up as null for serv 2. If I do it for serv2 it will show up as another service like DD for serv1.

My sum isn't working I would like to sum all of the services up by school but I'll take what anyone is willing to help me with. Any help is appreciated

```
 SELECT SPE_Student_Profile_VW.school_code,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.organization_name AS [[[School Name]]]]]]],
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.sis_number,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.primary_disability_code,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.secondary_disability_code,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.tertiary_disability_code,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv1,
   SUM (SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins1),
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv2,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins2,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv3,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins3,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv4,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins4,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv5,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins5,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv6,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins6,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv7,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins7,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv8,
   SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins8
 FROM DBO.SPE_Student_Profile_VW SPE_Student_Profile_VW
 WHERE (    SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv1 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
    AND SPE_Student_Profile_VW.school_code = '47')
GROUP BY SPE_Student_Profile_VW.school_code,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.organization_name,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.sis_number,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.primary_disability_code,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.secondary_disability_code,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.tertiary_disability_code,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv1,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins1,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv2,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins2,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv3,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins3,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv4,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins4,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv5,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins5,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv6,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins6,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv7,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins7,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv8,
     SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins8
```

Comment: Please add example data and example results.  See [ASK] if you need help.

Comment: If you want a sum per school, you should be grouping by school instead of all the columns in the table.

Answer (score 1):

the column you are trying to sum should not be in the group by clause, all the others should.

What I mean is the SELECT clause has this:

```
SUM (SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins1),
```

and the GROUP BY has this part which should not be there:

```
SPE_Student_Profile_VW.mins1,
```

because it is the column he is trying to sum and you can't group by a column that you are aggregating with a function and that is why SUM isn't working

Answer (score 0):

not sure of what is required but from what I get, you can probably get what you need if you add another

```
OR
```

in your

```
WHERE
```

Something like

```
WHERE (SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv1 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND SPE_Student_Profile_VW.school_code = '47') OR 
(SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv2 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND SPE_Student_Profile_VW.school_code = '47') OR
SPE_Student_Profile_VW.serv3 = 'Speech Language Therapy'
AND SPE_Student_Profile_VW.school_code = '47'
```

and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Group by clause use all columns which you are used in select statement.Except the column you are calculating sum in select statement.

Thanks.